# Utf8 in MySQL (and seen well in phpMyAdmin) but why not display correctly in web page (charset-utf8)?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, turkish

I have a table in mysql that utf8_turkish_ci encoded. Also the colomn has encoded as utf8_turkish_ci (varchar 250). But Turkish chars are not displayed properly. Manually written  Turkish Characters in body displayed correctly. I checked the header. Page header is:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:405
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 25 Sep 2013 04:50:39 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.7
```

Turkish chars are: Üü İı Öö Ğğ Şş

Web page side

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<?php
```

I want to stay in utf8. How can i get data from MySQL and correctly display them in web page? I tried many of solution suggests out there :/

Comment: Check that the MySQL connection itself is using UTF8. The best way I've found to do that is to do `SET NAMES utf8` as a query to the database as the first thing after opening the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using `set names utf8`. If using `PDO`, you can do the following in your connection to the database

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
]);
```

Comment: I cant understand. I tried mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); before. But not worked. But now with your suggest, like a charm! Thank you very much. Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

put this line just above your query of selecting data.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

hope this will help.